# Django user ldap to search all names from a group

Tags: python, django, ldap

```
AD_DNS_NAME = xx.xxxxxx.org'
AD_LDAP_URL = 'ldap://%s' % (AD_DNS_NAME)
con = ldap.initialize(AD_LDAP_URL)
    username = 'john'
    password = '123'
    base_dn = 'OU=Domain Users,DC=xx,DC=xxxxx,DC=org'
    filter = '(sAMAccountName=' + username + ')'
    attrs = ['mail']
    dn = '%s@%s' % (username, AD_DNS_NAME)

    try:
        con.simple_bind_s(dn, password)
        my_search = con.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter , attrs )
    # my_search return 
   #[('CN=john,OU=x_x_x xx,OU=xxxxxx,OU=CN BU,OU=Domain Users,DC=xx,DC=xxxxxx,DC=org', {'mail': ['john@xxxxxx.com.cn']})]
```

above code can search the info of a certain user named "john', but i don't know how to get all the members' name from a mail group, who know how to do this? for example, i want to search a group named "All of AAA"

I set the attrs to null and get all the info as below: i delete some other unimportant info

```
[ 
   ('CN=John,OU=C_E_S XX,OU=Mycity,OU=CN BU,OU=Domain Users,DC=xx,DC=xxxxxx,DC=org', 
     { 
        'mailNickname': ['John'], 
        'primaryGroupID': ['513'],
        'memberOf': [ 'CN=All of AAA,OU=CN BU,OU=Distribution List,OU=Exchange,DC=xx,DC=xxxxxx,DC=org', ], 
     } 
   )
  ]
```

could you please tell me how can i set the filter: filter = '(&(objectClass=group)(CN=groupname))' set group='memberOf' and groupname='All of AAA' ???, i have tried this but it does not help

I have resovle this problem, now i write down the method:

```
filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=All of AAA,OU=CN BU,OU=Distribution List,OU=Exchange,DC=xx,DC=xxxxxx,DC=org))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter like this:

```
filter = '(&(objectClass=group)(CN=groupname))'
```

And change your attrs variable to null to have it return all attributes

Comment: I set the attrs to null and get all the info as below:
i delete some other unimportant info, 

    [
       ('CN=John,OU=C_E_S XX,OU=Mycity,OU=CN BU,OU=Domain Users,DC=xx,DC=xxxxxx,DC=org', 
       {
        'mailNickname': ['John'], 'primaryGroupID': ['513'],  
 'memberOf': [ 'CN=All of AAA,OU=CN BU,OU=Distribution List,OU=Exchange,DC=xx,DC=xxxxxx,DC=org', ], 
       }
       )
    ]
could you please tell me how can i set the filter:
      filter = '(&(objectClass=group)(CN=groupname))'
set group='memberOf' and groupname='All of AAA' ???, i have tried this but it does not help

Comment: the display name is "All of AAA" and alias name is "AllofAAA"